# How do I stop visual studios from adding functions while creating forms?

Tags: visual-studio

I've always been annoyed that visual studio always thinks a double click means create an action function while creating a form. Sometimes I double click on a label to change the text like I do in other programs then I have to delete code and click back to the form editor.

Is there a way to stop this when I'm setting up a form then turn it back on when I am ready to code?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1511689/1271037 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8439113/1271037

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better off as a comment, but I lack the rep to comment.

You can't stop this behaviour.

The simplest (and as far as I'm aware, only) "solution" (read: workaround) is to just CTRL+Z twice when this happens (doing it once will cause your form designer to show an error, because the event binding will exist in the form, but the associated code won't exist).